# Bad url exception when using accented characters in url

Tags: ios, afnetworking, non-ascii-characters

I am using AFNetworking to fetch data from the server.

When there is an accented character in my URL I get an error like this:

> userInfo={"NSUnderlyingError"=>#<__NSCFError:0xfd3aa70,
>   description="bad URL", code=-1000, domain="kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork",
>   userInfo={"NSLocalizedDescription"=>"bad URL"}>,
>   "NSLocalizedDescription"=>"bad URL"}>

However, when I try the URL from a browser (chrome), my backend API returns the results fine.

Here is a sample URL I'm trying: `http://localhost:9000/my/Jalapeños`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A URL requires to be properly encoded. Given your example is a string representing a URI, it's definitely wrong.

You may take a look at `NSURLComponents` (available for OSX >= 10.9 and iOS >= 7.0) and [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).